# Shell script to Move a folder if it does not contain a file with a specific character

Tags: bash

I am using `freeNAS` and I need to move folders to another folder but only if there is a file within it that does not contain a special character [in my case a `(` or `)`].
Is there any way this can be done?  I have found ways to move files that have specific characters in filenames but not for this scenario.

Comment: Contains in the file or the filename ?

Comment: give us a ls print. We need an example with 2 folders; one has to be moved and not the 2nd one.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
destinationFolder="~/destination"
searchFolder=$PWD

for folder in `ls -lrth $searchFolder| grep "^d"| awk -F '{print $9}'`
do
    fileCount=`ls $folder|wc -l`
    findCount=`find ${searchFolder}/${folder} -type f | xargs egrep -v "\(|\)"`

    if [[ $fileCount -eq $findCount ]]; then
        cp -rp $folder $destinationFolder
    fi
done
```

The script is based on one assumption that the folder which you are trying to copy has only files in it and has no subfolders in it. If there are subfolders in it, change the logic accordingly.

If the assumption is as per your expectation then go ahead and use this small script. Let me know if this met your need.

Comment: I added '#!/bin/bash' to the start then executed it in the folder with './custom' the result is 'awk: no program given

Comment: when I tried $PWD for the directory it gave me permission denied. could it be a permission thing for $PWD?

Comment: Did you understand the program?